# Can't run any Ionic application after upgrading Mac to 10.12

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, macos-sierra

**Whenever I Launch an Ionic app with "ionic serve" I get this error bellow**

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.7.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ watch: `ionic-app-scripts watch`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ watch script 'ionic-app scripts watch'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! ionic-app-scripts watch
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've deleted the node_modules and done 'npm install'.
I've updated Node npm and Ionic and uninstall and reinstalled them.

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere, I believe it might me because of the Sierra upgrade but no one else seems to have the same problem I do

Comment: Try the commands `npm cache clean` , `npm install -g npm` , `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ `

Comment: I fixed it, I reinstalled everything but this time without home-brew and it worked, It worked before but I had to manually update the ionic-scripts to 0.0.29, something really strange was happening.

Thanks a lot anyway!